# What is "Could not locate the assembly" error?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(0,0):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
>   make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation errors.

an any body tell me what is this message?

When I am deploying my ASP.net MVC application using TFS i am getting this error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that this mean that you don't have MVC2 installed on the target machine and it's warning you that when the app is compiled there it will fail.

Comment: Please can you tell me what is the procecure to do this one?

Comment: @kumar http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/2.0/WebProductList.xml&appid=MVC2 (open on target machine, not on developing machine)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to install MVC 2 on the computer you are deploying to.

Answer (score 0):

Set "Copy Local" to "true" on the System.Web.Mvc in the References of your project and deploy with System.Web.Mvc.dll in your bin folder.

Comment: Can you check that it is copied to the right folder during deployment? Not much to do here, but put it where the compiler is looking for it.